# Pause stream when it encounters a certain value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream which I would like to pause / dwell whenever a certain value is encountered. What's the most elegant way to go about this?

Imagine the magic number is 4 - that will prevent any other values emitted for x amount of time. It will also prevent 'stale' values being emitted if they occur during the pause, but after the pause, it will switch to the most recent value

```
Source +-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
Pause          +----x
Output +-1-2-3-4----67-8-9
```

Comment: James, you're probably going to need to provide additional information for people to help you with this. Marble diagrams are normally a good way of expressing desired behaviour of reactive streams. Perhaps see if you can design the marble diagram of the behaviour you're describing above?

Comment: By pause do you mean that subsequent values should be delayed?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added an ascii marble diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CombineLatest()` to combine the source with another observable, which handles the pause state. After the combine use a simple `Where()` to filter the entries which are currently paused. See the following source code:

```
ISubject<bool> pause = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);

IObservable<long> original = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

IObservable<long> controlled = original.CombineLatest(pause, (o, p) => {
    return new { o, p};
})
    .Where(it => !it.p)
    .Select(it => it.o);

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
controlled.Subscribe(it => {
   Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} - {it}");
});

Thread.Sleep((int)(3.1 * 1000)); // wait for 3.1 seconds
pause.OnNext(true); // pause it 
Thread.Sleep((int)(3.5 * 1000)); // wait for 3.5 seconds
pause.OnNext(false);  // resume
Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000); // and finally wait for 5 seconds
```

This will generate the following output:

```
1017 - 0
2009 - 1
3007 - 2
6608 - 5
7007 - 6
8007 - 7
9007 - 8
10007 - 9
11007 - 10
```

As you see, the values `3`, `4` and `5` are initially blocked/ignored, but when the pause flag is resumed the last value `5` is "resend" again as soon as the pause flag is resetted (after 6.6s). After that the normal interval values are emitted.

Comment: Good idea - why didn't I think of that?

Comment: This doesn't behave in the way that the OP asked for.